# Android custom view: can't add own styles

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles

I've found an improvement that may help not to hardcode view values into java classes in my android app. I wonder how can i get it to work. I want to to use this kind of view in my adapter (that means that i cannot use @style attribute in my layout's root). What am i doing wrong?

Code:

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="customViewStyleRef">@style/CustomViewStyle</item>
    </style>

    <attr name="customViewStyleRef" format="reference"/>

    <style name="CustomViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

View class:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.customViewStyleRef);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.customViewStyleRef);
    }

    public void init(@NonNull ViewGroup parentView) {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_view, parentView);
    }
}
```

View layout:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:text="test text"/>
</merge>
```

Problem: The TextView container does not have any padding that i specified in styles.xml (see the image).

[image: Image of my project files and emulator]

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the TextView, then use the style for the TextView or you can solve this problem by putting style name inside the TextView and use an id for the TextView it will help for using it.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_tv"
        style="@style/CustomViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="test text"/>
```

Comment: But i want to use <merge> element

Comment: [ContextThemWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) might be help you
`TextView myText = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(MyActivity.this, R.style.CustomViewStyle));`

Comment: Context wrapper approach works, but sets wrapped style for nested children. This may help in several situations, but in my occasion i want to avoid this. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think i've figured this out. My built files were somehow cached and i couldn't get it to work. And i took a wrong testing parameter. My approach worked